# normalize vector with respect to the infinity norm python 3

Tags: python-3.x

This is the code I'm trying to write im new to coding so im sure im way off any help would be great. Thank you in advance.
Write a function normalize(vector) which takes in a vector and returns the normalized vector with respect to the infinity norm. i.e. (1/infNorm(vector)) * vector.

```
def normalize(vector):
    infNorm(vector) = abs(vector[0])
    for i in vector:
        if abs(i) > norm:
            infNorm(vector) = abs(i)
            finalvector = (1/infNorm(vector)) * vector
    return finalvector
vector = [2, 5, 7]
print(normalize(vector))
```

Comment: Help me remember one thing here. Infinity norm would be the sum of the absolute values of a vector, right?

Comment: To post code, paste it in, select it, and click the `{}` widget.  That will shift it right 4 spaces, causing it to be rendered as code.  Avoid tabs unless they're 4 spaces.

Comment: @luz.arthur: according to wikipedia, it's the max of the absolute values.

Comment: @JeffLearman That is correct, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing function call parameters using `()` with sequence indices `[]`.  By sequence, I mean a Python sequence, which includes things like tuples and lists.  Here, you're using a list as a vector.  (You could also use tuples, but only if you don't plan to modify them.  So we'll stick with lists, for generality and simplicity.)

Also, you need two loops: one to find the norm, and one to apply it.

```
def infnorm(vector):
    norm = 0
    for i in range(len(vector)):
        if abs(vector[i]) > norm:
            norm = vector[i]
    return norm

def normalize(vector):
    norm = infnorm(vector)
    return [v/norm for v in vector]

vector = [2, 5, 7]
print(normalize(vector))
```

Results:

```
[0.2857142857142857, 0.7142857142857143, 1.0]
```

Note that I didn't take the absolute value of each element before normalizing it.  I'm no vector wizard, so that might be wrong, but I'm guessing that the normalized vector can have negative values.

The last tricky bit, the return value for `normalize(vector)`, is called a "list comprehension".  It's a nifty python trick to build a list using a formula.  They look odd at first, but with a little practice it gets easy and they're quite precise and clear.  Check it out.

Comment: Compare my `ifnorm()` function with @luz.arthur's.  His is simpler, looping through vector elements.  Mine loops from 0 to the vector length minus 1, and indexes to get the vector element values explicitly.  There's something to learn from both approaches, though his code is better, and using the `max()` function is the best way to do it (but not the best way to learn how to access vector elements.)  Also compare my `normalize()` function with his.  They both do the same thing, so it's a good way to understand two ways of building lists.

Comment: Thank you your help was very helpful

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to use a for loop to find the maximum value of an array in python, I'd suggest splitting the normalize function in two functions, one to get the infinity norm and another one to calculate the vector, as such:

```
def infNorm(vector):
    norm = vector[0]
    for element in vector:
        if norm < abs(element):
            norm = abs(element)
    return norm

def normalize(vector):
    norm = infNorm(vector)
    new_vector = []
    for element in vector:
        new_vector.append((1.0/norm)*element)
    return new_vector
```

Otherwise, you could use the [max()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#max) built-in function from python, with such function, the code would look like this:

```
def normalize(vector):
    norm = abs(max(vector, key=abs))
    new_vector = []
    for element in vector:
        new_vector.append((1.0/norm)*element)
    return new_vector
```

By the way, when you have a symbol, followed by parenthesis, you are trying to invoke a function.So, when you do `infNorm(vector) = abs(vector[0])`, you are trying to assign a value to a function call, which will result in a syntax error. The correct way would be just `infNorm = abs(vector[0])`.

Comment: Thank you your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The infinity norm is the sum of the absolute values of the elements. For instance, here is what sagemath offers for one vector, for the infinity norm, the 2-norm and the 1-norm.

[image: norms]

In general to normalise a vector according to a norm you divide each of its elements by its length in that norm.

Then this can be expressed in Python in this way:

```
>>> vec = [-2, 5, 3]
>>> inf_norm = sum([abs(v) for v in vec])
>>> inf_norm
10
>>> normalised_vec = [v/inf_norm for v in vec]
>>> normalised_vec
[-0.2, 0.5, 0.3]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: The best way to say "thanks" on StackOverflow is to just click the up-arrow to up-vote the answer or comment.